# Not able to send data to database, nor showing any error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send data to my database but nothing is sent. nor it is showing any connectivity error. nor any error in PHP code.
I have made two files one common connectivity file for db dbh.inc.php
which I have called in the main php file.

DATABASE CONNECTIVITY :

```
   <?php
   $dbServername = "localhost";
   $dbUsername = "root";
   $dbPassword = "admin";
   $dbName = "musicianshub";
   $conn = mysqli_connect ($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword,$dbName);
```

PHP code:

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'dbh.inc.php';



      $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
      $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
      $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
      $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);


      if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || 
      empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
      }

      else {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $fist) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-
        Z]*$/", $last)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
            exit();
        }
        else {
              if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=email");
                exit();
          }
          else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_phone='$user_phone'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                  header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=phonetaken");
                  exit();
                }
                else {
                  $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, 
                  user_email, user_phone, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', 
                  '$last', '$email', '$phone', '$hashedPwd');";

                  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


                  header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                  exit();
                }

          }
          }
          }

         }
         else {
         header("Location: ../signup.php");
          exit();
          }
```

can anyone have any idea about it. 
Thank you.

Comment: First; please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even though you are using `mysqli_real_escape_string` you may still be vulnerable to an injection attack. Second; please make use of [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get any query errors to display. I'll check over your code now to see if anything else strikes as a potential issue.

Comment: if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

try this code to get started with. There are errors you just don't see them.

Comment: okay, I'll look for it. Thank you @pr1nc3

Comment: What is the `signup` parameter in the url where the page redirects. Does it show `signup=empty`, `singup=invalid`, `signup=email`, `signup=phonetaken`, `signup=success`, or simply nothing. In addition, you may need to comment out the redirecting `header()` statements before seeing errors.